# How to show all tweeted data in XML file through twitter api?

Tags: xml, twitter, tweets

When I've typed in browser address bar `"https://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.xml?id=Valid_Twitter_USER_ID"` then it will show a last tweeted xml data of my account. It's 
perfect for me, but I want to get all tweeted data from my twitter account. So could you tell me how to get this data through this method? or is there any other method or api to get all tweeted data from my account.

Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

With the api function you are using you cannot get the tweets as I undestand the documentation.
Have a look at the good documation for the API from twitter at this url dev.twitter.com/docs

I think the functionality you are looking for could be reached by combining the uri you have posted to get the information of your user acccound, and use  this https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline to get the lates tweets.
As the documentation states you use this by calling the uri `https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=twitterapi&count=2` where twitterapi is replaced by your id or screen name.